# how to create some dynamic sprites falling from top to bottom

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am making a game in cocos2dx(c++).Here i have to make dynamic sprites that are falling top to down and on touch i have to kill them.I mean the sprites are of insects and they will be killed on touch
The problem is that I am unable to get the idea on how to implement them as on increasing the level the insects will be falling more and with more speed.
I have made for one insect.But don't know how to handle for multiple insects

Comment: Are you using multi-threading?  I saw some comments below that suggested you may be.  If you are using multi-threading, you should not do that with cocos2d-x.

Comment: Can you post some code showing where the problems are occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, your 1st Sprite is coming from y height and it fell to -y/2 with a velocity of 10.
Then, you have to make several sprites with differnt velocities and different positions of x.
You can move a sprite in cocos2dx with the help CCMoveTo()

Comment: actually i have to kill them also by touch began on it.But the problem is when it kills only the first insect and it doesn't kill the next ans the thread bad access error comes. The current sprites in the scene should be dynamically assigned to some temporary array of sprite and then killed.I am unable to find a code on this.Could you send a demo code

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRYJNUhF03g   just see this video..teh zombies are coming from top and getting killed....mera concept same hai

Comment: Buddy! i already developed this type of game. So,if you need my help send me your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custome method to move sprite

```
void GameLayer::_mov(CCSprite *cp, float x, float y)
{
    cp->setPositionX(cp->getPositionX()-x);
    cp->setPositionY(cp->getPositionY()-y);
}
```

In this method we passing sprite which we have to move and `x` is how much change in sprite position and `y` is how much change in sprite position. In this I subtract x and y from the current position of sprite but you can add also according to your requirement.

You have to call this method in your update method.